# Tree tournament in prolog

Tags: prolog

Could u help me please? I want to make a knockout tournament. I don't know the prologue very well, so i don’t know how this is could implemented in the prologue.

```
tournament:- consult("E:\\teams.txt",team),start0.  
start0 :- shapka,one_screen2, 
findall(X,team(X,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_),L1),
findall(Sc1,team(_,_,Sc1,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_),PlayerScore1),
findall(Sc2,team(_,_,_,_,Sc2,_,_,_,_,_,_,_),PlayerScore2),
findall(Sc3,team(_,_,_,_,_,_,Sc3,_,_,_,_,_),PlayerScore3),
findall(Sc4,team(_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,Sc4,_,_,_),PlayerScore4),
findall(Sc5,team(_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,Sc5,_),PlayerScore5),
scoreteam(PlayerScore1,PlayerScore2,PlayerScore3,PlayerScore4,PlayerScore5, TeamRating),
start1(L1,TeamRating,X1,X2),
nl,menu2.

scoreteam([],[],[],[],[],[]).
scoreteam([P1|R1],[P2|R2],[P3|R3],[P4|R4],[P5|R5], [T|T1]) :- T =  P1 + P2 + P3 + P4 + P5,scoreteam(R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,T1),!.


start1([X],[R],X,R).
start1([H|T],[W|E],H,W):-start1(T,E,M,Z), M<>H,nl,write(M," vs ",H),nl,W<>Z,write(Z," vs ",W),!.
start1([_|T],[_|E],M,Z):-start1(T,E,M,Z).
```

As long as i only have this. I take teams from the database, add up the points of their players and put them against each other.
My in ideas were like this: when comparing points, toss a coin, the team which has more points, the chance to win in a coin is greater, and after the victory, the winning team must fight with another winning team, and after each victory, the team gets points. How to implement this? Any ideas?

Comment: Give us some input and output you are expecting for that input.

Comment: @rajashekar no input is needed, everything that needs to be entered is entered already in the database, and the output should be for example: "Team1 vs Team2" (team points are compared for example: Team1 have 300 points,Team2 have 250 points, by the method of comparison, determine the chance of winning in coins, more the better), and next line: "Team 1 is winner". Next match: "Team 1 vs Team4(according to the same scheme, the winner is recognized between team 3 and team 4)"

Comment: @Peter: you are consulting a facts file which probably have the `team/8` facts.